# Bring feed information over all our chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, feed

I use several chat rooms. Each has a specific feed that appears in the *slide-down ticker overlay at the top of the room*. But I see the feed only if I am in the chat room with the specific feed configured.

If I switch rooms, I want to have feed information from all my chat rooms displayed where I am. Would that be possible?

A configuration setting for whether or not you want the feed cross-chat would be great too.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's the choice of the room owner(s) to add feeds to the room; usually because that very room has a specific topic for which the feed is interesting. So e.g. the Python room on chat.SO gets the feed with the newest [python] questions on SO.

If you have a lot of feeds you'd like to watch, you'd probably be better off using your favorite RSS aggregator. The chat surely isn't the right tool for that.